# Delete header Sample Excel file saved as PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am working on a Excel report that takes data from another Excel Workbook, imports the data and does statistical analysis. This is moved to a worksheet and graphs are generated from the data. All of this is formatted for printing. In the Macros that are written to do this is a sub macro that takes this Report and saves it to a network drive for uploading and also shows the PDF so you can print it.
The problem: when it creates the PDF it adds a line to the top of the PDF that states "Sample Excel file Saved as PDF". This is also on the saved PDF that will be uploaded as part of file in our HIS. 
How do I not get this on the PDF. It is not part of, and should not be on the PDF.

Below is the code I use to setup the PDF save and Print it.

```
Sub Save_PDF()

     Dim Path1 As String
     Dim Path2 As String
     Path1 = "c:Test Result\...\"

'Range where spefic file name is placed for this occurance

     Path2 = Range("A79")

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .PrintArea = "$A$1:$AE$75"
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
    End With

'Setup saves as report and place in drive for upload to HIS

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        filename:=Path1 & Path2, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False
```

Comment: This may not be an Excel issue, but the PDF print driver.  Try printing a Word document to a PDF and see if you get something similar.  You may have a Freeware software driver and they often append some type of header/footer to printouts until you make the purchase.

Comment: Thanks I'll check that out. This is a corporate computer and office suite, with no special addon that I am aware of. The Network has a driver for CutePDF that I sometimes use from Word, or Excel and have never had this issue. I'm using the xlTypePDF from in the VBA. I'm not sure how to call the CutePDF driver from VBA or if I can. I have gone through the Print settings that I know about and there are no headers/footers or odd margins that I can find.

Comment: Recommend recording a macro of your manual Excel print job. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you use the same driver here that you use to print manually, since there you have no issues.  I recorded a macro for my system below and then added the `PrToFileName` parameter.  Recommend you do the same and integrate it into your code.

```
Sub TestPrinting()
' TestPrinting Macro

    Application.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft Print to PDF on xx01:"
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, ActivePrinter:= _
        "Microsoft Print to PDF on xx01:", Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        PrToFileName:="C:\Users\juna\Desktop\TestPDFPrint.pdf"

End Sub
```